# Label for="class"

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to asign a label for to a class name?
This is my code:

```
    <input type="radio" id="answers1" name="answer1" value="1" checked>
       <label for="answers1" class=lfirst>1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="answers2" name="answer1" value="2">
       <label for="answers2" >2</label>
    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="answer1" value="3">
       <label for="answers" for="answers" >3</label>
    <input type="radio" class="answers" name="answer1" value="4">
       <label for="answers" >4</label>


    <style>
    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      background: #2C337B;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    </style>
```

My first 2 radiobuttons are clickable because the label for is asigned to the id name of the radiobutton. My 2 other buttons are not clickable because the label is asigned to a class. Is there anyway to change this? Or is it OK to just use id's (total would be over 600 same id's names)?

Comment: No because a label is designed to be linked to a **single** element. Having an ambiguous label would defeat the object of it.

Comment: in your case just place input inside label tag: <label><input />some text</label>

Comment: @IgorBenikov I've added the input between te input tags, but now when I click on it my label won't change color like it did in my example

Answer (score 0):

yes, you cannot have a label pointing to the class, that's because label should be assigned to only 1 element, and should you know, classes are not uniqe (but ID's are)

on the other hand, you can do some jQuery workaround, like this:

```
$('label').on('click', function(){ // after we click a label
   var el = $(this).attr('for'); // we get its "for" attribute
    $('.' + el).focus(); // prepend it with "." to make a class name, and then focus on objects with that class
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? Just did a bit of basic jquery at the moment

Comment: @Jnb ok, I have made some comments

Comment: This should give undefined behavior when you have a number of elements with the given class.

Comment: @Pawel_W In my css, I just have to put:
.ans input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      background: #2C337B;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

If I make my label for="ans"

Answer (score 0):

You can give same class to different elements. But label is unique to identify the element. You can have unique labels for your radiobuttons and "`label for`" can be assigned to each element.

If you are using `label for` only for associating it with the radio button, then no need for it. You can directly give the `radio`button inside the `label` tag

Comment: I've added the input between te input tags, but now when I click on it my label won't change color like it did in my example